# Can't seem to remove RootFS verification on Chromebook

Tags: google-chrome

I'm following the instructions from https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/poking-around-your-chrome-os-device

Here's what I've tried:

```
localhost usr # /usr/share/vboot/bin/make_dev_ssd.sh --remove_rootfs_verification

  ERROR: YOU ARE TRYING TO MODIFY THE LIVE SYSTEM IMAGE /dev/sda.

  The system may become unusable after that change, especially when you have
  some auto updates in progress. To make it safer, we suggest you to only
  change the partition you have booted with. To do that, re-execute this command
  as:

    sudo ./make_dev_ssd.sh --remove_rootfs_verification --partitions 4

  If you are sure to modify other partition, please invoke the command again and
  explicitly assign only one target partition for each time  (--partitions N )

ERROR: IMAGE /dev/sda IS NOT MODIFIED.
localhost usr # /usr/share/vboot/bin/make_dev_ssd.sh --remove_rootfs_verification --partitions 1
INFO: Partition 1: no kernel boot information, ignored.
ERROR: No valid kernel partitions on /dev/sda (1).
localhost usr # /usr/share/vboot/bin/make_dev_ssd.sh --remove_rootfs_verification --partitions 2 
INFO: Making change to 2 on /dev/sda.

  ERROR: YOUR FIRMWARE WILL ONLY BOOT SIGNED IMAGES.

  Modifying the kernel or root filesystem will result in an unusable system.  If
  you really want to make this change, allow the firmware to boot self-signed
  images by running:

    sudo crossystem dev_boot_signed_only=0

  before re-executing this command.

ERROR: IMAGE /dev/sda IS NOT MODIFIED.
localhost usr # sudo crossystem dev_boot_signed_only=0
Parameter dev_boot_signed_only is read-only
localhost usr #
```

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Crouton following this tutorial http://jeremyckahn.github.io/blog/2013/02/09/setting-up-a-local-development-environment-in-chrome-os/

Now I'm able to do what I was looking for